# Motion of a pendulum described by 2 equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors

I have a pendulum at the extreme position of its motion. I broke the forces into the  components, and I have two equations. But, which of them is correct? They can't be true simultaneously. But by the diagram, both of them seem to be true.

[image]

Comment: you could have rotated your image before asking for help! lol..

Comment: Please read this following  link, as homework questions are not answered on this site. Although you may receive a hint. http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-0/Pendulum-Motion

Comment: Have you thought about whether or not the bob has an acceleration? And if so, in which direction? At right angles to this direction the force components will add to zero.

Comment: Check your trig again for the first one.

Comment: What is your physics reasoning for writing those equations? (Neither one of them is written in a good conceptual form, IMHO. ) That should tell you which one is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Equation 1 is wrong.  As you say they can't both be right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a pendulum. Tcos(theta) always changes since pendulum follows a curved way while swinging. But the mass of the pendulum will not change. Thus, we can't say that Tcos(theta) = mg all the time and since pendulum at the extreme position of its motion, first equation is wrong.

Comment: Nobody said that ia has to be so all the time. The equations are supposed to apply to the extreme position of the pendulum only.

Comment: This doesn't really justify it being wrong.  If $T cos (\theta ) = mg$ you can still vary $T$ and $\theta$ to make them equal to $mg$ even if $mg$ doesn't change.  That logic would mean that equation 2 is also wrong; since you can write it as $\frac T {cos (\theta ) } = mg$, and you once again, can't vary $m$.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with variation of m or the angle.  Look up Newton's second law.  You don't need to make them equal.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer of Dr Chuck, when you write Newton's law you should not forget about the acceleration term (in F=ma). You are free to choose the axes as you wish but cannot expect that the components of acceleration are the same on different axes systems. At the extreme position it happens that the radial acceleration is zero but this does not make the vertical component zero. The equation written for the vertical axis (the first one) is incomplete.

Comment: so what will be the complete equation

Comment: Read again the second comment to your question. You need to show some effort. You were given some hints.

Answer (score -1):

In principle, both of the above-mentioned equations can be correct but one should fix the target physical question.

We can define the total forces acting on the mass "m" in cylindrical and polar coordinates as
$$
\begin{align}
F^{c}_{\rm tot} &= T \cos \theta \hat{z} - T \sin \theta \hat{\rho} -mg \hat{z}, \\
F^{p}_{\rm tot} &= - T \hat{r} + mg \cos \theta \hat{r} -mg \sin \theta \hat{\theta} ,
\end{align}
$$ 
where
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{z} &= - \hat{r} \cos \theta + \hat{\theta} \sin \theta ,\\
\hat{\rho} &= \hat{r} \sin \theta + \hat{\theta} \cos \theta.
\end{align}
$$
Substituting the above relation back in $F^{c}$ and using the relation $\cos^{2}\theta + \sin^{2}\theta=1$ will result in the second equation($F^{p}$).

Thereby, along $\hat{z}$, from the first equation ($F^{c}$), we would have $T\cos \theta = mg$, This enforces that the particle would undergo a motion in the horizontal circle(z-fixed plane), please see [here](https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2F9kZyY.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fphysics.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F151317%2Fminimum-angular-velocity-for-circular-motion-pendulum&docid=s3KLWJPGM3-ZkM&tbnid=THl_Zc287ToSmM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiTraXMy-_UAhXKPxQKHSr-BwoQMwg9KBIwEg..i&w=420&h=363&client=ubuntu&bih=1326&biw=2495&q=pendulum%20in%20plane&ved=0ahUKEwiTraXMy-_UAhXKPxQKHSr-BwoQMwg9KBIwEg&iact=mrc&uact=8). This circular motion has been addressed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151317/minimum-angular-velocity-for-circular-motion-pendulum).

From the second equation ($F^{p}$) along $\hat{r}$, we can have $T=mg \cos \theta$, which would describe a pendulum that oscillates in the polar plane, like [here](http://www.tutorvista.com/content/physics/physics-i/wave-motion-sound/restoring-force.php). A more detailed solution can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#math_Eq._1).

Comment: You seem to be talking about multiple different scenarios here; but I don't really see why.  Briging up a pendulum rotating in the horizontal plane isn't useful; it confuses the problem further.  If you look at the equations the OP used; you can see it's a simple trig error; and has nothing to do with what is said here.

Comment: By the 2D plotted picture, you are right. But in general, the other equality would also be valid if we would allow the pendulum to rotate in the z-fixed plane. Thereby, as the physical aim in not clear, both relations can be assessed.

Comment: That's not what the question asks about though.  He's wondering why based on his diagram he gets 2 different values for tension.  The answer is simple; he did the math wrong.  It doesn't really help to show relationships that give both the equations when it has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Where is the math error? The problem is physics, the vertical component of acceleration is not zero. The radial is.

Comment: But where is the math error??

Comment: @JMac But where is the error

Comment: @user8167818 You used trigonometry wrong when you found $mg = T cos(\theta )$.

Comment: @JMac But Cos (theta) = b/h . since h=  T , b = T cos ( theta)

Comment: @user8167818 your mistake, in your first eqution, is rooted in the fact that the "$T \sin \theta$" force is along the direction which, if it is not treated in the cylindrical coordinate, would lead to a motion of a particle at a fixed-z, and would violate the conservation of the pendulum length. Whereas in the suggested solutions the length of the pendulum is always fixed.